# Simple C matrix multiplication, multi thread

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a standard C base matrix multiplication code, where I create an individual thread for each row and column pair. I am getting a blank screen where the main gets stuck for ever and program never ends. Could you please have a look at it
I want to first create all threads and then join all threads respectively.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size 10
#define M size
#define K size
#define N size

// int A [M][K] = { {1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6} };
// int B [K][N] = { {8,7,6}, {5,4,3} };

int A [M][K];
int B [K][N] ;
int C [M][N];

struct v {
   int i; /* row */
   int j; /* column */
};

void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */

void fill_matrix(int matrix[][N], int row, int column)
{
   // int (*matrix)[row] = malloc(sizeof(int[row][column]));
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
      matrix[i][j] = (rand() % (100-0+1)) + 1;
    }
  }
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   int i,j, count = 0;
   // int (*A)[M] = malloc(sizeof(int[M][K]));
   // int (*B)[K] = malloc(sizeof(int[K][N]));
   // A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(A));

   fill_matrix(A,M,K);
   fill_matrix(B,K,N);
   clock_t start = clock();
  // pthread_t thread_array[M*N];
    pthread_t thread_array[M*N]; //malloc(M*N * sizeof(pthread_t));

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   int idl[M*N];
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
         //Assign a row and column for each thread
         struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
         data->i = i;
         data->j = j;
         /* Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter */
         //pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
         //pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes
         //Get the default attributes
         //pthread_attr_init(&attr);
         //Create the thread
        idl[i]=count;
         pthread_create(count,&thread_array[count],&attr,runner,data);
         //Make sure the parent waits for all thread to complete
         //pthread_join(tid, NULL);
         count++;
      }
   }
   for(int k =0;k<M*N;k++){
   pthread_join(&thread_array[k],NULL);
   }
  free(thread_array);
     clock_t end = clock();
     printf("%f\n",(float)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
  
   //Print out the resulting matrix
   //for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
   //   for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
   //      printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
   //   }
   //   printf("\n");
  // }
}

//The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param) {
   struct v *data = param; // the structure that holds our data
   int n, sum = 0; //the counter and sum

   //Row multiplied by column
   for(n = 0; n< K; n++){
      sum += A[data->i][n] * B[n][data->j];
   }
   //assign the sum to its coordinate
   C[data->i][data->j] = sum;

   //Exit the thread
   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Please ignore the comments in code, I know there are many.

Comment: *"Please ignore the comments in code"* - If you want us to ignore them, then remove them instead

Comment: Have you tried running the algorithm in serial, without threads? You should start there.

Comment: I cannot compile your code with gcc

Comment: Your code has lots of warnings and does not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `free(thread_array);`, you did not `malloc` it, so you don't need to `free` it.

`pthread_join(&thread_array[k],NULL);` should be `pthread_join(thread_array[k],NULL);`, as it is taking the `pthread_t` and not a pointer to it.

The first parameter in `pthread_create(count,&thread_array[count],&attr,runner,data);` is wrong, remove it ==> `pthread_create(&thread_array[count],&attr,runner,data);`.

You do not use the `isl` array, so remove it.

After that it compiles, runs and gives an output, at least: https://ideone.com/1r0e2V